# Using Semantic UI menu like a sidebar

Tags: semantic-ui

I am new to Semantic and I would like to use the `menu` look like the `sidebar`. As in I want the Menu to look like how it would if the sidebar is visible.

I had the same problem as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33444883/13165955) question, and the solution suggests to use `menu` instead of `sidebar`. But I am lost trying to implement this.

I used the same example as in the semantic-ui website.

```html
    <div class="d-flex pushable">
      <div class="ui left vertical inverted sidebar labeled icon menu visible">
        <a class="item">
          <i class="home icon"></i>
          Home
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          <i class="block layout icon"></i>
          Topics
        </a>
        <a class="item">
          <i class="smile icon"></i>
          Friends
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="pusher">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Any help is appreciated.